# Convert a textual representation of a float to actual numeral using command line

Tags: bash, shell, perl, binary, floating-point

I have a `double` printed as text. Is there a way to pass that source text number to some utility in order to get the actual numeral i.e. the nearest actual representable double value? Either in decimal/binary/hex?

E.g. that the text `3.472727272727276` is actually `3.47272727272727621539161191321909427642822265625`

**Update:**
I am looking for a way to get the floating point number that's closest to `3.472727272727276`, and not any one floating point number that rounds to it

Comment: What is the output expected? nearest float or a decimal ?

Comment: @Inian: Ideally all cases i.e. be able to get the decimal and binary and hex in the nearest possible representable value. If not then what ever is possible via command line

Answer (score 4):

Would this do?

```
dash$ printf "%.99f\n" 3.472727272727276
3.472727272727276215391611913219094276428222656250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

or

```
dash$ printf "%.99f\n" 3.472727272727276 | sed -e 's/0*$//'
3.47272727272727621539161191321909427642822265625
```

That's the output from Dash, which agrees with what I get with Zsh, a simple C program<sup>(*)</sup> or with Perl (`perl -e 'printf "%.99f\n", 3.472727272727276'`). On the other hand, Bash seems to give more precision, I didn't look into what the printf there uses for floats.

<sub>(* compiled with the default options on x86_64 Debian, so it uses SSE for floating point.)</sub>

The width `99` is of course pulled from a hat. With 53 significant bits in a double, 17 base-10 digits should be enough to to get an unambiguous representation, but to get the exact value, you need something like 53 base-10 digits again, for a number with an integer part around one. If it's scaled up or down, you'd need more digits, possibly more than 99, or exponent notation (`%g` perhaps).

This is off the top of my head, and there may be mistakes or corner-cases. I'm not going to go deeper into the maths of floating point, here, there should be articles about that from people smarter than me already online.

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

The short answer for an **exact** number is (using dash for [double floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)):

```
$ dash -c 'printf "%a\n" 3.472727272727276'
0x1.bc8253c8253dp+1
```

In bash we get [extended double floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) (80 bits) and therefore more digits:

```
$ bash -c 'printf "%a\n" 3.4727272727272760001'
0xd.e4129e4129e7c1fp-2
```

There is no `%a` format in awk nor zsh, in ksh the conversion may fail.

If what you must have is a decimal conversion, the number of digits could be as high as 16450 digits for the **exact** conversion. The command must be:

```
$ printf '%.16450g\n' 3.472727272727276
3.47272727272727600006906045759791368254809640347957611083984375
```

Which takes advantage of the fact that the `g` format removes all trailing zeros (but most of the time it uses an scientific exponent).

Note that down to 1e-4931 (toward zero) is a [valid extended float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) and that that number does indeed generate 16445 digits in `f` format<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)</sup>

That count of digits is close to the count of binary fractional digits:

```
$ printf '%a\n' 1e-4931
0xb.e5b66ecbce0b7b1p-16384
```

And 11516 digits (the last 6 characters are the exponent) in `g` format:

```
$ printf '%.16445g\n' 1e-4931 | wc -c
11522
```

---

## Full description

The answer from @ilkkachu is imprecise//incomplete

Yes, we can get more digits (fractional digits, or, non-integer digits) by just asking for more (in some cases):

```
 $ printf '%.10f\n' 0.5; printf '%.25f\n' 0.5
 0.500000
 0.5000000000000000000000000
```

But why stop at 25 or 99 or 250 or 2500 ? Where is the limit ? Where should be the limit ?

#### double

For the printf implemented in GNU awk on Linux we can get up to 53 digits { for numbers in the range 0.5=<x<1 or: [0.5,1). So the first bit of the mantissa is 1 with an exponent of "0" (zero) }.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ printf "%.56f\n", 0.6 }'
0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375000
  123456789_123456789-123456789¯123456789|123456789_123456789-
```

That is because the normal double in C, and used by awk by default has a mantissa of 53 bits (yes there are as many fractional decimal digits as are fractional binary digits).

#### Extended float

But in bash (and some other implementations) the size of a double float is as big as it could be inside the math co-processor, a mantissa of 64 bits for an 80 bits float.

```
$ printf "%.70f\n", 0.6
0.6000000000000000000216840434497100886801490560173988342285156250000000
  123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-
```

But be careful, dash use C double floats and ksh cuts fractional decimals at 18 digits:

```
$ dash -c 'printf "%.70f\n" 0.6
0.5999999999999999777955395074968691915273666381835937500000000000000000
  123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-

$ ksh -c 'printf "%.70f\n" 0.12345678901234567890'
0.1234567890123456790000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-
```

#### Longer decimals

If the number to print is outside the range `[0.5,1)`. Well, actually, if the number is below that range, the number of digits generated by `printf` (to be exact) must increase, an small exponent of `-12` is enough to get more than 99 decimals:

```
$ printf '%.99f\n%.110f\n' 1e-12 1e-12
0.00000000000100000000000000000000260071239141640525192192084057152268
  1727856252109631896018981933594
0.00000000000100000000000000000000260071239141640525192192084057152268
  172785625210963189601898193359375000000000
```

#### normals

If the mantissa is adjusted to have the first **binary** bit as `1`, following the IEEE-754 spec, the exponent could be as big as (negative big) binary 1022 (or around decimal 308) which will require 1022 + 53 = 1075 decimal digits to be exactly printed (using dash for C language double float):

```
$ dash -c 'printf "%.1080f" 3e-308'
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000030000000000000002220455218529919301629802590703175094461
8147776231970806960868915174651286204183765077257126691146784826970001182
3377333217966211682361285986313366061022263946269900386622216365532374597
7178280811925489426908651787672688372272916552149728525251396407136469620
5940554355008967838740787733222562854087120536535403422962140580707820507
1667528534455025639283299437942142025335784795886380202690541431449127657
8638018769522816220159645085115105872872349792947642929427853637000376104
4766449778622710769965927963092807311828491559718885849370616714002362927
2391454493281372654969535173285036362816688696655266375211946090175421780
9466790102733774958189714097426504991570081907927842237039897170724535065
396560619562470184629177083479589782655239105224609375000000
```

But it is a lot easier, and one of a fixed width, to use the `%a` format:

```
$ dash -c 'printf "%a" 3e-308'
0x1.59283684dba77p-1022
```

The exact same number but a lot less than the 1080 digits needed above.

#### Subnormals

However, IEEE754 also allow **subnormals** which extend the fractional range to even smaller (toward zero, not negative) numbers. In double floats that could get to 2<sup>-1074</sup>. That is 1022 (max exponent) + 52 (binary bits in the mantissa)

```
$ dash -c 'printf "%a\n" 0x1p-1074' 
0x0.0000000000001p-1022
```

That number would require at least 1075 digits in decimal (Try `dash -c 'printf "%.1080f\n" 0x1p-1074'`

#### math

The reason to require that many digits is only math.

The exact result of 0x1p-60 (1 binary bit 60 positions to the right of the decimal separator) is simply 1/2^60, or 2<sup>-60</sup>:

```
$ echo 'scale=65;1/2^60' | bc
.00000000000000000086736173798840354720596224069595336914062500000
```

The math forces that result. Again: there must be as many decimal fractional digits as there are binary fractional digits.

### Exact?

But to give you a short method to calculate the float that a number should produce: try:

```
$ number=3.472727272727276; 
$ echo "x=$number"'; f=floor(x*2^53); l=f/2^53; u=(f+1)/2^53;l;x-l;u;u-x' | bc

3.47272727272727599334       # one ulp below
 .00000000000000000666
3.47272727272727610436       # one ulp above
 .00000000000000010436
```

And select the one with the smaller error, 3.47272727272727599334 in this case. That is not the same as the exact IEEE754 representation. But you can be certain that this number will give you exactly that:

```
$ dash -c 'printf "%.100g\n" "3.47272727272727599334"'
3.472727272727275771302402063156478106975555419921875
```

An ulp means: Unit in the last place.

#### IEEE-754

And most of the above is assuming that the float representation conforms to the IEEE-754 rule of "round to nearest (the number closer to 0.5) and ties to even (if the distance to the nearest number is equal both up and down, round to an even number (in simple terms: make the last bit `0`)).

So, with the number in your question:

```
$ arr=(
3.4727272727272765 
3.4727272727272764 
3.472727272727276  
3.472727272727275994 
3.472727272727275993
); dash -c 'printf "%a\n" "$@"' _sh "${arr[@]}"

0x1.bc8253c8253d1p+1
0x1.bc8253c8253dp+1
0x1.bc8253c8253dp+1
0x1.bc8253c8253dp+1
0x1.bc8253c8253cfp+1
```

From a number 1 bit above (ends in `3d1`)to one number 1 bit below (ends in `3cf`). In bash, with 64 bit mantissa, the numbers are different.

```
arr=(
3.47272727272727600018
3.47272727272727600017
3.472727272727276
3.47272727272727599997
3.47272727272727599996
     ); bash -c 'printf "%a\n" "$@"' _sh "${arr[@]}"

0xd.e4129e4129e7c2p-2
0xd.e4129e4129e7c1fp-2
0xd.e4129e4129e7c1fp-2
0xd.e4129e4129e7c1fp-2
0xd.e4129e4129e7c1ep-2
```

---

Note <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)</sup>

Note that down (toward zero) to 1e-4931 is a [valid extended float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) and that that number does indeed generate 16445 digits in `f` format, a bit forward down:

The count of digits is close to the count of binary fractional digits:

```
$ printf '%a\n' 1e-4931
0xb.e5b66ecbce0b7b1p-16384
```

And 11516 digits (the last 6 characters are the exponent) in `g` format:

```
$ printf '%.16445g\n' 1e-4931 | wc -c
11522
```

```
printf '%.16450f\n' 1e-4931 | fold -w 73
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000082071899211
7338292331024160232487820585348161247770186041314033840500051545008634353
6341360688983242486478141174400757940479009877109594292525504227462920421
2893412961654118443870700320472323231587805993105589329896961394013763260
4659993978247248517682208361484994779731694489944630063321405732960902413
2163826064625704556138246247291713512226186038110522361712282167677484499
4853485029854756356981823466893512864152476213489101964761352653855914067
5407404554688679242643694555765705916896595658042111013963304042194443434
2454458747320616647767965588654942541534222361345871520329192555602083886
7547668572049684141329499463147471364250757050352758439157993233018887765
3022453676305812302609741465722408673611869206684449107816484217162193316
0451417277376429998715700300103481261322468543881150650589114548116214409
0282610286947933274302831898960425132335516929267570658616807675594145055
7933527421286297306761087201890796722576805103111314970478492002310801919
5121110163059112312817278127472248186627786955410431004987964809727320826
3836867323863772424448077582741295606931866923958341785438440563570256923
3967214120760775046056499093488836286605925343014122920758357587042372478
4396732691590332416323376272386092941667490819065164058104132980059594910
2359008778669430615206773524319389966040554373094729579913188959958627665
0147054467689808335379318394367256072691585884193608098888834608988382517
9555400409255856681227954996219960904103899921767062227771904748352771827
3303956905161469311714970152690453526924382380410750656562412220963352392
0138329683948383338163097529599320269353721943944454940376358960836594051
3477809670299461167943887751256622044357084988532778474147865932282204513
2633031930514791856749172748713829709085669263868478956239297247880404451
7368621008068442797986335305249411008216146904415412953950001882685540890
1556780918561125527285831756180981771417450660976541919429826985921645962
9201276409873470500605529929901418584423540341991427848245574167168319010
4166469700540637579260581881947825466347482642862250106630069466021160621
5708653897225676975925511960349151350001134049757024302430257175193997151
4982583219749199092690545023085582866284162001345019227038307956196555313
3519516264189415251526792337107425827902360506088057955371784256616880268
3481205336046002789486284348178440170365034867338331652138861540971130253
9542269303050756935715270218806051136916996994319794858917896049906836482
7098398097827598580501664683202268902944648499801054993782628057786176349
9449403495561979111666771243943855744591594357175824358242664803240527503
7148981242949373077459055909120180426976328575611957482241886416886211456
4930533398315196939976469817186321830188058540785650068798616643153690897
1940003879624967405611779261257525540023345461636845524670403087434346354
2300902544572850469518439699765019550766539135275097854278939353265696979
8834439096861503266152867799080072157759748288907251319272957731038577344
6431535245545698319281988357996617254365469308202774764740270854428603109
0658615753163113372339326411333232695409430506796247862594824568714833737
6674586371616805578466172913102227164198256143554413339537206357013935647
0629147463681431162377855171292192075881285675544153979212279809633985848
6334720344048971403943003525729450686409883850490551307376237219794673145
1653521240236521969952971585422347256435489320408561433650553103621455311
4825379034920452163728194090871162565598571949541087264160366180879574884
7819973416435197872598418339953363758686913035927347605455007312010618225
2828781277896065251773210967393707756631839487624825752098569131518756381
8690024525152574157236464871652272646121213102628343423336658149133356868
0369390118251770450805020724331465525880295410904068122148550596391967976
0316372115721602906220401313546472893783885616487703074861532346434272567
6224887474718310372062434586017607508533640557298220265750588802657706884
1693715814060119176032809782368663807174910909867486843554494925790524702
2031454968860083834785048633719298029480406551563759326376458111133240080
9698676957085570003118431611007159904209095042061060056423179809759196141
4108228361780274366531731138323313273681795576174095447144561045234599507
6194227134059621083310577760480057291678454291609721473582990228292540584
7220152621542912717003056021400306862489029876623758468497347264800874607
0497564237799785255002204618467705426645994152603385213467462034868618759
6633615825771097366076405047236201921116428307785583745881849366988656930
4302932168354392028644558853067798145554385777127229140625369490000350171
7559648569526198722677883475465020803420776799839602027139286574802455505
5877425049471921303153011216333972815390192361918768620432643150220777026
9680664979099411443029479808238132526688405016406158058997404062685329277
8241393302275315995842312417759250272227533486142904065678940422293350276
7203185521092408789420562060743369693606635936966347020642524897059008713
0158900278592357012894977200992010323826650352236074791326375411649637745
3519624557227329410191105559631041359100689648672626758464563528279434070
6558861509034283932042786689140310681834581009319560349264357315869377969
0302342784950817743454555744064071757290206549636942369479300063807726601
4973130615209027727652018171049564772625669399319459667802043887151818927
0913007155076328707170438989171553671079133742732822879041887229643704411
7994537547047353258871121305054842843542796775044150453846116399521780197
9624014103419501566178264222606070672010510722876673981273167332243256347
4806399532467024709317233368476276538450476543327702712741827328531530516
8027452699430898999586455447912321706037983393869869116869533400495367526
9546599949891779321156363085470874912518167220155265668782927447585394430
4589389441354100333269682720945176587402534578669914176804302733519255081
6995225641510029537563527890130860311540130715201023031728098017613991470
3483399577777809438470383159919342130015156112047027093916390919511507067
9670949411987546768987778079492478658451834978153443354874815200900094231
4958501308259918525527660731683142370346393328300310341022636916428566795
7624045891594912799639484227530275255452455097007726048348405587238026906
8634839251501318761932980321595999925102874807697110350629814584949360001
0680569268640879656258950821472425241292977629113054752520768368498712813
8774779740352315078536495546752896630365075412806083752886940393508156073
2275973501778358814827394939018156615658996586168025320784231072816933142
1012119309903361777338434095371972077777452601237743248745297771758443641
6968057282662265405821486417797838733581015224793213178771040499907889109
8963868657262075556880875732945083109532749608889962171094671623215548952
5306729982647609691564425884156297847144585709595292678579425356237357661
1599905758458570672049159672577629038125316394764910688253665918240477217
2459880682984941647880958671566709581394666870839203949370147168699057682
4144213210355871252797074724369111002103225755201311770129872114061047250
3572583472994177568157818016370472655636868696163564156841497932751415551
4054399238261660551508979593580236452432644011215789164004824799421288575
6997136597512053635021414518486207889687047868791414291468455916652931744
6682385590455472216331449166098060976877012505305265332308885737370798411
2725626373268176421826458747928372841263266637656660438845686727544294945
2690409328436471588375041890680077843753361526503346420772132736189763619
0743125914239769186593726307040846501626923902778436228935545472737248075
9837098497713009771388513415495825241853072828615345985426683350304637479
3241759111233728652179997966456508271393109708213930113893292248134528947
1864720250066111635407231630503132446789566208148505683562744658068944141
2176763349569613208625955031082770724859616752930500433914086810162010332
8465544727575357452056287590038912201729249559136253934801272421518080981
3482497161481781427803465758781721485086990522812778083440253206147373153
8203190179060590427820681162660018061978736914735502525227260018995153233
4548744879049725174666244415047143525206158723933135742603063097731323001
9188477305926749422574968513760489776845793866735248660626517733066291276
9521699068103623420436933705434785080757836075993330683487467266964453873
6041680104189957969298117847857451608257496710247702743091623329036849828
2474848502495408070287264413464278241453971937423643215298338277231386632
6535804834059400142159998762478268182576630301631284608460319558650432439
7688697130946098414046196391821710541882311331763705241923212390150611868
8382878259522225960440343867915599168453706644187027504744329285460718970
9401423772209288751463874247042841877765178129971845107461934158634348157
7604782604324648156665366186743460902192919583923668275936193147254234835
3187828117397892973176526172961616396094409907459519671456596657956236025
7401140687132852748716608964429415825316417570402144690186097773166585181
5244604234308190093946630362184441850826684698698051645445312186068907062
7747013328711255353328059749477357400479282173802131826411440029181903503
7642889730442208783021486746051763738418541632162894842300184029117102598
7676300955574169711628720697151542322143558873329293629652673727281786564
9027103118642421603958290605283732674929235464650604072669705986934327957
4075211371759701017127636026867567013347746367072700059587018284856132864
0603722970670691579369151252734445464940156185578309071940283023400634249
3197631830698256169063269720324505427514591791691710637291716980761237752
1190446177555454831085057970699801769297580670961946286158353530479993518
9994158988703723706693241887541252760548498993853198982508802119679398436
8475841280472034059193462912965691282055673940207226669422761933873980890
3924874969239271549878166762474786850994394225482471626471215800710963517
8181247863830954360607641366578301895367549124331764944461762189065453644
5989425740478921174999111964495482782370655137527056146182445621663389820
5384785827250536885617707904791700750980086566655659828536506480170049592
4961909321581267958692430947172417095953440484887539558329471582318012707
8386678196042147650662800983106000230357490132344860626176658696008989847
0076556287596629652818855103814345376715161441991252866232721070835845827
1508346190487940553908756085264037077637032418626064298317239500267475797
0832165547139152633344499837604073185037992646476800301052096864917050261
6193735444674272010048722584970917704976440854009997555675729981901025377
0175837813545335548742484568580361302734737863811644913004930626198447295
7384004372181671677617373464890753787837631800814040379317934407502212060
0538663391885863933785814489604984908211973633635434683306924801097885769
0043030319076078838022212269137579914972477155817617608658275145902737104
4238345871797750951221233673324503360895728299779461034741047557521429449
4460368001069027669242117982221568073292320372854649034794646767407536970
2208793986432395527861092876058703741893206338205857836251867009420808654
7871983682029963788845367410649878293896713671520949635535984162032177787
1936102468137705442800457558532609694236313360798713636061527283622983764
6616763247230283561579958054279369454755161009643889534807265004319636567
6155935065884876198961972374410893199540128857327754010864181509959101002
3687953152830468752077945559092362782483458343838727884626485906456312211
6423993561968165983510511297069817964719989022981611988669061612451909740
5229476488947169595602453426354812106997125656955014329072733974629875789
2524141933958367922861260290466997220510844327675246435982447934520678245
462477207183837890625000000
```

Comment: Amazing! I need to spend at least a couple of  hours to really understand the details!

Comment: Thank you very much for all this information!

Comment: @Jim Added `math` and `exact?` sections. Those should completely fill the circle. Should you have any more doubts, please ask.